# Smart Contract calling another contract not effecting any changes

Tags: abi, solidity-0.8.x

I have two smart contracts, a LeaderBoard contract and a Reward contract.
I have the Reward contract call the LeaderBoard contract to add/update values, and I am testing everything using HardHat and Chai. But After making the calls needed, I do not see the leaderboard getting updated.

LeaderBoard contract:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

contract LeaderBoard {

    struct LeaderBoardKeyStore {
        string gameName;
        int gameId;
        int gameScore;
    }

    mapping(string => LeaderBoardKeyStore[]) addressLeaderBoard;

    string[] keysNames;

    constructor() 
    {}

    function getThisContractAddress() public view returns (address) {
        address myAddress = address(this);
        return myAddress;
    }

    function setLeaderBoardScoreForApp(string memory keyAddress, string memory gameName, int gameId, int newLeaderBoardValue) external {
      if (addressLeaderBoard[keyAddress].length == 0) {
        keysNames.push(keyAddress);
      }


        addressLeaderBoard[keyAddress].push(LeaderBoardKeyStore(gameName, gameId, newLeaderBoardValue));
    }

    function num_of(string memory key) public view returns (uint) {
        return addressLeaderBoard[key].length;
    }

}
```

And this is my Reward contract:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

import "./LeaderBoard.sol";

contract Reward {

    address payable public sponsorAddress;

    address payable public winnerAddress;

    uint public gameAmount;


    address leaderBoardSmartContractAddress;
    Leaderboard lbContract;


    constructor(address payable _sponsorAddress, uint _amount) payable 
    {
        sponsorAddress = _sponsorAddress;
        gameAmount = _amount;
    }


    function approveReward(string memory _gameName, int _gameId, int _newLeaderBoardBoost) external payable {      
            (bool sent, bytes memory data) = winnerAddress.call{value: gameAmount}("");

            require(sent, "Failed to send Ether");

            string memory stringAddr = addressToString(msg.sender);

            //This is supposed to call the specific instance of the smart contract (the address) that we specify in setThisContractAddress 
            lbContract.setLeaderBoardScoreForApp(stringAddr, _gameName, _gameId, _newLeaderBoardBoost);    
    }

    function setWinnerAddress(address payable _winnerAdress) public {
        winnerAdress = _winnerAdress;
    }


    function setLBContractAddress(address _leaderboardSmartContractAddr) public {
        leaderBoardSmartContractAddress = _leaderboardSmartContractAddr;
        lbContract = LeaderBoard(_leaderboardSmartContractAddr);
    }

   function addressToString(address _addr) public pure returns(string memory) {
        bytes32 value = bytes32(uint256(uint160(_addr)));
        bytes memory alphabet = "0123456789abcdef";
    
        bytes memory str = new bytes(51);
        str[0] = '0';
        str[1] = 'x';
        for (uint256 i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
            str[2+i*2] = alphabet[uint8(value[i + 12] >> 4)];
            str[3+i*2] = alphabet[uint8(value[i + 12] & 0x0f)];
        }
        return string(str);
    }
}
```

and in my hard hat tests I have the following:

```
describe("Describe Test", function () {
  it("Test cross talk of contracts", async function () {
    const [owner, winnerAddr] = await ethers.getSigners();
    
    straddr = "0x8626f6940E2eb28930eFb4CeF49B2d1F2C9C1199";
    checksumedAddr = ethers.getAddress(straddr);

    var appName1 = "AppName1";
    var appName2 = "AppName2"
    var appid1 = 1;
    var appid2 = 2;
    var appScore1 = 3;
    var appScore2 = 4;
    
    const lb = await ethers.getContractFactory("LeaderBoard");
    const lbContract = await lb.deploy();

    await lbContract.setLeaderBoardScoreForApp(owner.address, appName1, appid1, appScore1);
    var result = await lbContract.num_of(owner.address);
    expect (1).to.equal(result); 
    //This passes when I try to add in an entry into the leaderboard directly to the LeaderBoard smart contract



    var amount = 1000;   

    const myRewardContract = await ethers.getContractFactory("Reward");
    const rewardContract = await myRewardContract.deploy(owner.address, amount);

    var lbContractAddress = await lbContract.getThisContractAddress();

    await rewardContract.setLBContractAddress(lbContractAddress);


    await rewardContract.approveReward(appName2, appid2, appScore2);


    var result = await lbContract.num_of(owner.address);
    //Should be 2 since the first one was added directly and the second one should be added by a proxy call
    expect (2).to.equal(result); 
   
  });
});
```

This is my first time programming smart contracts and especially two different ones calling each other's methods. Is there something I am missing or misunderstanding about their interactions or am I targeting the wrong address when I am querying the LeaderBoard smart contract? I believe you can deploy multiple instances of a smart contract each having it's own address aka it's own instance (I come from an OOP background so I am trying to tie these concepts into terms I already know)